# how can i find an object from an array [ i want to find findIt object from cartItem ]

Tags: javascript

```
const findIt = {
    productId: "htm-45",
    attribute: [
        {name:"size",index:2},
        {color:"red",index:2}
    ]
}

const cartItem = [
    {
        productId: "htm-45-34",
        atrributeId:"_672349e",
        attribute: [
            {name:"size",index:1}
        ]
    },
    {
        productId: "htm-45",
        attribute: [
            {name:"size",index:2},
            {name:"size",index:3},
        ]
    },
    {
        productId: "htm-45",
        attribute: [
            {name:"size",index:2},
            {color:"red",index:2}
        ]
    }
    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const idToSearch="htm-45"
const findIt = cartItem.find((item)=>item.productId===idToSearch)
```

Go through [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)